# Runtime measure count of Azure storage transactions

Tags: azure, azure-storage, billing

Is there any way to get a number of blob/table/queue transactions from an account at runtime (not bill time)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the newly-released [Windows Azure Storage Transactions](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazure/archive/2011/08/03/announcing-windows-azure-storage-analytics.aspx). In the Metrics schema, you'll see both TotalRequests and TotalBillableRequests (these are aggregated hourly).